# How to use custom background image or color using Promotion

Tags: rubymotion

I am trying to build an iOS app using Promotion. It works fine as long
as I use the build in default design. But I want to be able to style for example
the navbar as I want (different colors and different background images).

How can I do this using Promotion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Teacup to easily customize your views. https://github.com/rubymotion/teacup

Add teacup to your gemfile, create a file appearence.rb in app/styles/appearence.rb and paste the following code:

```
Teacup::Appearance.new do

  style UINavigationBar, {
    tintColor: UIColor.blackColor
  }

  style UIBarButtonItem, {
    tintColor: UIColor.blackColor
  }

  style UITableViewCell, {
    layer: {  # style the layer!
      shadowRadius: 3
    },
    backgroundView: {  # style the background!
      backgroundColor: UIColor.blackColor
    },
    imageView: {  # style the imageView!
      contentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
    }
  }

  style UISearchBar, {
    tintColor: UIColor.colorWithRed(0.733, green:0.733, blue:0.733, alpha:1)
  }
end
```

Add this line to your app delegate before loading your views

```
Teacup::Appearance.apply
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This absolutely works. I'm using it in my app. I haven't a clue how UIAppearance will work in some "as-yet unreleased" version of iOS, but for iOS 6, it works just great!